# Decagon is a sphere, connected sum of $n$ tori of connected sum of $n$ projective planes

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider the surface with identification $a b c d e c^{-1} d a^{-1} b^{-1} e^{-1}$, I am trying to see if it corresponds to a sphere, a connected sum of $n$ tori or a connected sum of $n$ projective planes.

I know the sphere corresponds to $aa^{-1}$, the connected sum of $n$ tori to $a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}a_2b_2a_2^{-1}b_2^{-1}...a_nb_na_n^{-1}b_n^{-1}$ and the connected sum of $n$ projective planes to $a_1a_1a_2a_2...a_na_n$.

We already have the identification so if we eliminate the adjacent edges of the first kind we would have $dd$. This means the surface is a single projective space, am I right?

Comment: What else do you know or tried?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Call this surface $X$. After the identification, $X$ contains $1$ vertex, $5$ edges, and $1$ face, so the Euler Characteristic of $X$ is $\chi(X)=1-5+1=-3$. We also have $X=M_g\# N_k$ by the classification theorem of surfaces, where $M_g$ is the connected sum of $g$ tori and $N_k$ is the connected sum of $k$ projective planes. This gives us the following equality:

\begin{align*}
&\chi(X)=\chi(M_g)+\chi(N_k)-\chi(S^2)=2-2g+2-k-2=-3\\
&\implies 2-2g-k=-3\\
&\implies 2g+k=5
\end{align*}

Solving in non-negative integers

- $g=0,\ k=5$
- $g=1,\ k=3$
- $g=2,\ k=1$

It turns out that these spaces are all homeomorphic (both the orientability and euler characteristics agree). Hence, we may assert that $X\approx T^2\# T^2\#\Bbb RP^2$.

---

Note: An alternative method is to compute the homology groups.

Comment: Thanks! How do you get the number of vertices, edges and faces from the identification?

Comment: @anthony5859 A regular decagon has ten vertices, but by identifying all the edges in pairs, you also identify the ten vertices, so there is only one in the calculation of euler characteristic. (you may draw a diagram to visualize why it is true)